# Can you have two Navigation Controllers in subviews of a Main UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ipad

The following image explains what I'm trying to do:

http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/1475/multinav.png

This is for an iPad app. Is it possible? And if so, can someone post the skeleton code to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried UISplitViewController?

Comment: Both NavigationControllers on the right & left are independent from each other

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  Skeleton code:

Header file:

```
@interface SGBSplitViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIViewController *leftViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIViewController *rightViewController;

- (id)initWithLeftViewController:(UIViewController *)leftViewController
             rightViewController:(UIViewController *)rightViewController;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
@implementation SGBSplitViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    return nil;
}

- (id)initWithLeftViewController:(UIViewController *)leftViewController
             rightViewController:(UIViewController *)rightViewController
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self)
    {
        _leftViewController = leftViewController;
        _rightViewController = rightViewController;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addChildViewController:self.leftViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.leftViewController.view];
    [self.leftViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self addChildViewController:self.rightViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.rightViewController.view];
    [self.rightViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.leftViewController.view.frame = <frame>;
    self.rightViewController.view.frame = <frame>;
}
```